# Calling a special function from within namespace

Tags: r, function, namespaces, package, scoping

I'm interested in calling a special function from a namespace *without* the need to load the package. For instance, as described on [**R-bloggers**](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-write-and-document-special-functions-in-r/), the package [**`mefa4`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mefa4/index.html) developed by Peter Solymos offers a convenient function `%notin%`. The function is of a simple syntax:

```
"%notin%" <- function(x, table) !(match(x, table, nomatch = 0) > 0)
```

## Example

I would like to make use of this function without the need to load the package. The attempted [syntax](/questions/tagged/syntax):

### Attempt 1

```
1:10 mefa4::`%notin%` 7:10
```

results in an error:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "1:10 mefa4"
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘sp’ was built under R version 3.3.2
```

### Attempt 2

```
mefa4::`%notin%` c(7:10, 1:10)
```

returns:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "mefa4::'%notin%' c"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the function using:

```
mefa4::`%notin%`(7:10, 1:10)
```